# How to render template and layout from different directories with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

I want to put template files in defferent directories. (foo/, bar/)

How do you write using Sinatra?

[image]

This way get wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html):

```
set :views, Proc.new { File.join(root, "templates") }
```

If you want to use multiple directories (also from the docs):

```
set :views, ['views', 'templates']

helpers do
  def find_template(views, name, engine, &block)
    Array(views).each { |v| super(v, name, engine, &block) }
  end
end
```

By the way, you need to reference templates with symbols, not strings. So the complete code would be:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'haml'

set :views, ['foo', 'bar']

helpers do
  def find_template(views, name, engine, &block)
    Array(views).each { |v| super(v, name, engine, &block) }
  end
end

get '/' do
  haml :index, :layout => :bar
end
```

and you have these files:

```
foo/index.haml
bar/bar.haml
```

Comment: I want to put 2 files separated directories. (foo/index.haml, bar/layout.haml)